# Python 3: Extracting Data from a .txt File?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have this file that has data set up like this:

```
Bob 5 60
Carl 7 80
Rick 8 100
Santiago 7 30
```

I need to separate each part into three different lists. One for the name, one for the first number, and one for the second number.

But I don't really understand, how exactly do I extract those parts? Also, let's say I want to make a tuple with the first line, with each of the different parts (the name, first number, and second number) into a single tuple?

I just don't get how I extract that information.
I just learned how to read and write text files...so I'm pretty clueless.

EDIT: As a note, the text file already exists. The program I'm working on needs to read the text file, which has its data formatted in the way I listed.

Comment: Maybe you wish to split an string using the space character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split each line on whitespace:

```
with open(yourfile) as f:
    rows = [l.split() for l in f]

names, firstnums, secondnums = zip(*rows)
```

`zip(*iterable)` re-arranges the 3 columns into 3 lists.

Answer (score 0):

Would not the module Pickle be ideal here?  Pickle gives Python functionality to load and save things that need to be 'useable' in Python, so instead of just importing a string from a text file and having to parse it, pickle can load it and give you the actual container you're trying to work with.

example:

```
import pickle

myList = ["Bob", 1, 2]
listToBeSaved = pickle.dumps(myList) # write this data to your save file
#insert code where you work with the file and save it
#.........    
#upon needing to open and work with this file
listToBeLoaded = open(fileYouWroteTo)
listTranslated = pickle.loads(listToBeLoaded) # turns the loaded data back into a proper list
```

Comment: I don't think pickle is a particularly good fit here.  The OP already has data in a specific format, which pickle won't read.

Comment: I suggested pickle b/c the zip() example, while doing a great job of just moving the data into a series of tuples, also just spits out a bunch of strings, as open(yourfile) does.  If the OP wants to work with the values that are (apparently) associated with the names, now they're writing more code to turn strings into ints.  If that's not relevant to their project and they don't care that they could just be saving/loading Python containers (or the data they are working with absolutely must be in this format, no questions about it), then no big deal.

Comment: My issue is that I already have a text file, and that I need to take information from that. I need it to be able to take any file, if it's in the format as in the OP and read it, basically. I can't manually create the list. >.<